# How to emit a Vue event into state

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuex, emit

How can I set an event value emitted from a component straight to the state in the data property instead of just calling a function first and setting it after
e.g

```html
<Input
  id="firstname"
  type="text"
  v-model="user.firstname"
  required
  p="p-2
  md:p-4"
  class="mt-2"
  errorText="First name field cannot be empty"
  :validation="user.firstname.length === 0"
  @valid="checkFirstName"
/>
```

But I want to set the value coming directly from `@valid` to  a key in my state

Comment: Please add a working snippet of the code you are working with; setters are normally the right way to go for these things, and the workflow you are trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @AaronMorefield alright done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value comes in as `$event` and you can set it directly to a data property:

```js
@valid="name = $event"
```

Since your question is tagged `Vuex`, maybe you want to call a mutation:

```js
@valid="$store.commit('SET_NAME', $event)"
```

I don't see a good reason for that when you could commit from the child.  If the question is about altering Vuex state without a mutation, no that's a violation and shouldn't be done.

Here's a demo:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<button @click="$emit('valid', 'myname')">click me</button>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    name: ''
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Name: {{ name }}<br>
  <child @valid="name = $event"></child>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```